# Vulkan pipeline derivatives

Tags: vulkan

I'm trying to use derivatives when creating graphics pipelines. I have two graphics pipelines that I'm creating that are exactly the same, except for the specialization info.

I create the first pipeline with the `VK_PIPELINE_CREATE_ALLOW_DERIVATIVES_BIT` flag and the second one with `VK_PIPELINE_CREATE_DERIVATIVE_BIT` flag. When creating the second pipeline I set the basePipelineHandle as the first pipeline. Is there anything else I need to do?

When using VkPipelineCreationFeedbackEXT `VK_PIPELINE_CREATION_FEEDBACK_BASE_PIPELINE_ACCELERATION_BIT_EXT` is not set, but `VK_PIPELINE_CREATION_FEEDBACK_VALID_BIT_EXT` is, so the feedback is valid.

Validation layers report no errors. I'm currently using nvidia 1060 gtx, is it possible that it just doesn't support pipeline derivatives?

Also at the moment I'm not using pipeline cache, but would combining pipeline cache with derivatives work?

Comment: Why do you think that it's not working? Also, why would you not be using a pipeline cache?

Comment: @NicolBolas because the `VK_PIPELINE_CREATION_FEEDBACK_BASE_PIPELINE_ACCELERATION_BIT_EXT` is not set. The cache bit is set if I use pipeline cache. Also the pipeline creation time does not change if I use the derivative or not. I will use cache later, does it make sense to combine the two?

Comment: I believe Nvidia drivers don't take advantage of derivatives, but they do take advantage of pipeline caches. Generally pipeline caches will give you more benefit on more drivers, though one or two do get some benefit from derivatives. But even then it's mostly if you have identical shaders between pipelines; I can imagine that changing specialization constants changes the (compiled) shaders enough that neither derivatives or caches will help much.

Comment: @JesseHall I tested it on amd and get the same result. Caches do help a lot, pipelines are created up to 20x faster.